# Objective-C: How to detect whether sender is UITextField or UISwitch

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm placing `UITextfield` and `UISwitch` instances in a `UITableView`. I can detect tags and values, but not sure how to detect if they are `UISwitch` or `UITextField`?

I intend to set different actions for each.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check the class of the sender like this:

```
if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UISwitch class]]) ...
```

However, this may not be the optimal setup: potentially you could wire up different selectors when you create your table cells with a switch vs. text field for a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by dasblinkenlight will always be true for all the sub classes of `UISwitch` for specific class you can also try this

```
if ([sender class] == [UISwitch class]])
```

Comment: if you want to be sure the subsets are excluded, you could use the `–isMemberOfClass:` method instead.